# Using Closure inside Angularjs $watch

Tags: javascript, angularjs, closures

I'm trying to use a closure inside $watch(it is used to watch the changes that occur in a dropdown) . I'm trying to set a value for a variable for the first running and then to replace it for the changes that occurs in the dropdown. I feel that closures are not working properly in the $watch. Please have a look here:

```
    $scope.$watch('myDropDown', function () { // it's watching the dropdown
        $scope.monthsGroup = $scope.yearAndMonthsGroup.months; // months loaded in the dropdown

        $scope.month = $scope.monthsGroup[0];// set the first month as default
        var runOnlyOnce = (function () {
            var called = false;
            return function () {
                if (!called) {
                    $scope.month = $scope.monthsGroup[$scope.monthsGroup.length -1]; // set the last month as default for first running
                    console.log("Run it!");//it is running it over again when changes occur in the dropdown
                    called = true;
                }
            }
        })();
    });`
```

http://jsfiddle.net/svaos5d9/

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`runOnlyOnce` runs indeed only once... for each instance created. The problem is that you are creating many instances, one for each time the watch is triggered.

Just place the `runOnlyOnce` creation code *outside* of the watch, and just *call it* inside:

```
var runOnlyOnce = (function(){
    var called = false;
    return function(){
        if(!called){
            $scope.month = $scope.monthsGroup[$scope.monthsGroup.length -1]; // set the last month as default for first running
            console.log("Run it!");//it is running it over again when changes occur in the dropdown                        
            called = true;
        }
    }
})();

$scope.$watch('myDropDown', function () {
    $scope.monthsGroup = $scope.yearAndMonthsGroup.months; // months loaded in the dropdown
    $scope.month = $scope.monthsGroup[0];// set the first month as default
    runOnlyOnce();
});
```